# Objection dependency inject framework - binding a class to a protocol

Tags: objective-c, dependencies, protocols, code-injection

I'm a bit confused trying utilize Objection for dependency injection, to inject a concrete class for a protocol property instance.  For learning purposes I was making a simple logger injection example as follows:

```
// Protocol definition
@protocol TestLogger<NSObject>
-(void)trace: (NSString*) message, ...;
-(void)info: (NSString*) message,...;
-(void)warn: (NSString*) message,...;
-(void)error: (NSString*) message, ...;
@end


// Concrete class definition following my protocol - note it doesn't actually use
// CocoaLumberjack yet, I just had an NSLog statement for testing purposes
@interface CocoaLumberjackLogger : NSObject<TestLogger> 
@end

// Implementation section for lumberjack logger
@implementation CocoaLumberjackLogger

-(void)trace: (NSString*) message, ...
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, message);
    [self writeMessage:@"Trace" message:message];
    va_end(args); 
}

//(note: other implementations omitted here, but are in my code)
.
.
.
@end
```

**Now I want to inject my logger into a view as a property so I do the following:**

```
// My test view controller interface section
@interface TestViewController : UIViewController
- (IBAction)testIt:(id)sender;

@property id<TestLogger> logger;

@end

// Implementation section
@implementation TestViewController

objection_register(TestViewController)
objection_requires(@"logger")

@synthesize logger;
. 
. 
.
```

**Lastly I have the application module setup:**

```
@interface ApplicationModule : JSObjectionModule {

}
@end

@implementation ApplicationModule
- (void)configure {
[self bindClass:[CocoaLumberjackLogger class] toProtocol:@protocol(TestLogger)];
}
@end

@implementation TestAppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:     (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    JSObjectionModule *module = [[ApplicationModule alloc] init];
    JSObjectionInjector *injector = [JSObjection createInjector:module];   
    [JSObjection setDefaultInjector:injector];
    return YES;
}
```

**The outcome**

Everything seems to run perfectly fine, only my logger property is nil in my test view when I click my test button to call a logger statement.  I was hoping it would have been filled out with an object of concrete class type CococoaLumberJackLogger.

Any ideas as to where I went wrong?  Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sean,

What is responsible for initializing the TestViewController? The TestViewController's initialization must be delegated to the injector.

For example, if a NIB is responsible for instantiating it then the logger would be nil because the NIB has no understanding of TestViewController's dependencies.

Comment: Hmm, yea I'm using story boards so I assume that's the issue.  I was thinking it was something along those lines but unsure if there was a way to set it up so that when the view controller was instantiated from the storyboard that there'd be a way to have it cause the injector to be invoked.  Thanks for the feedback.  I've generally been a C# (lately asp mvc) & have used ninject / structuremap for DI, I was trying to apply the same pattern.  I'll play around a bit, thanks again!

Comment: If you are using story boards the best thing you can do is have the controller use the default injector directly. For example, logger = [[JSObjection defaultInjector] getObject:[TestLogger class]].

Comment: Just to follow up, I am now calling the injector getObject specifying my protocol in the viewDidLoad methods of the controllers where I'm injecting my repositories and it's working well - good to go, thanks!

Comment: Is your code hosted somewhere? Or perhaps you could post a Gist so that others can benefit from your solution. Thanks.